# in grails 2.4.5 is there anyway to parametrize the required part of the g:textfield

Tags: grails, required

working in grails 2.4.5 is there anyway to parametrize the required part of the g:textfield, my current code looks like this and i want to eliminate the if statement....

```
<g:if test="${requiredData == true}">
    <g:field type="number" class="form-control" name="${entityField}" value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" required="" />
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <g:field type="number" class="form-control" name="${entityField}" value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" />
</g:else>
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy way to conditionally add or exclude an attribute is like this:

```
<g:field type="number" class="form-control" name="${entityField}" value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" ${requiredData ? 'required=""' : ''} />
```

For example, I've used that technique with the `disabled` attribute, since in such cases the mere presence of the attribute activates the functionality; the value is ignored.

Comment: I haven't tested mine and unsure if required="false" will work in all cases. This looks like a better way

Comment: @vahid, it doesn't. Setting the attribute to *any* value effectively means `required="true"` For a clue, take a look at how jQuery handles this attribute in this unit test: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/ddb2c06f51a20d1da2d444ecda88f9ed64ef2e91/test/unit/attributes.js#L350

Comment: Class
i wish that worked....  But it pukes for me, lol....       org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
Message
Expecting '=' after attribute name (class="form-control" name="${entityField}" value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" ${requiredData ? 'required=""' : ''}).

Comment: I swear I had done it that way, but as it always happens, could not find proof. I have seen it done using g:if. The syntax is ugly badly-formed HTML, but, give it a shot: `<g:field type="number" class="form-control" name="${entityField}" value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" <g:if test="${requiredData}">required="required"</g:if> />`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can overwrite g:field or write your own TagLib which will handle it. Base on [FormTagLib](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/0b1d6a6d02f2217643a69e8314f76078dacbce32/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy).

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
    <g:field type="number" class="form-control" name="${entityField}" 
     value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" 
     <g:if test="${requiredData == true}">required=""</g:if> 
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be via js. You can have:

```
<g:field type="number" class="form-control ${requiredField ? 'required-field' : ''}" name="${entityField}" value="${value}" min="${min}" max="${max}" />
```

and in js:

```
$(function() {
    $( document).ajaxComplete(function() {
        $(".required-field").prop('required',true);
    });
    $(".required-field").prop('required',true);
});
```